# JBoss Development Studio

Tags: jboss

Is there an update for this [tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Web_Framework_Kit/1.2/html/Spring_Developer_Guide/ch03.html)? I have the following problems:

1. Section 3.2, the src directory, wich is created automatically is different from that one, which I would created manually.
2. Section 3.3, its written "Right click on the project in the left hand menu to bring up dropdown box." -> "Select Spring Tools". But I could not found an entry Spring Tools.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not installed SpringIDE.

In previous versions of developer studio that was prebundled, but not everyone used it thus you now can optionally install it from JBoss Central.